# Create a shortcut that sends a broadcast

Tags: android, android-intent, android-broadcast

My application has the option to create home screen shortcuts.

I create the shortcut like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_INTENT,
new Intent(ShortcutCreateActivity.this, ShortcutCreateActivity.class).putExtra(EXTRA_PROFILE_ID, profileId).putExtra(EXTRA_PROFILE_ACTION, item));
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_NAME, profileTitle);
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_ICON, bitmap);
```

This works as expected... when the user clicks the shortcut, the ShortcutCreateActivity is launched and I do what I need.

However! I would like to avoid the need to open an activity. Instead, I want to create a shortcut that sends a broadcast.

I tried replacing the intent with:

```
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_INTENT,
    new Intent(INTENT_ACTION_THAT_I_WANT)
```

But when I click the shortcut, it shows a Toast "App isn't installed".

Is it possible to create a home screen shortcut that sends a broadcast instead of launching an Activity?

(Starting the activity and quickly finishing it is not an option).

Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is it possible to create a home screen shortcut that sends a broadcast instead of launching an Activity?

Strictly speaking, no.

However, you can have it point to an activity that is set up with `Theme.NoDisplay`, where in the activity's `onCreate()` you send your broadcast and call `finish()` without calling `setContentView()`. Visually, this is indistinguishable from having the shortcut send the broadcast itself.