# Shortcut: intent to broadcastreceiver?

Tags: android, android-intent

I added some dynamic *shortcuts* to my application:

```
ShortcutInfoCompat sc = new ShortcutInfoCompat.Builder(ctx, "key")
    .setShortLabel("Shortlabel")
    .setLongLabel("Longlabel")
    .setIntent(intent_in_question)
    .build();
ShortcutManagerCompat.pushDynamicShortcut(ctx, sc);
```

I wish to create an `Intent` which only executes this piece of code without any `Activity`:

```
Settings.Secure.putString(xy);
```

How can I do this? (Technically, I wish the shortcut to do `sendBroadcast`. )

Note: I found [Create a shortcut that sends a broadcast](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16134636/create-a-shortcut-that-sends-a-broadcast), but it's almost 10years old, and a lot of things has been changed during this time.

Comment: Have you tried the solution in the linked question? Basically, a shortcut can only launch an `Activity`, so if the solution in the linked question no longer works, you are probably stuck.

Android doesn't like it when you do things in the background without telling the user. Imagine what happens here: User clicks on your shortcut and nothing happens. So he clicks again, and again, and again.

You are probably using the wrong approach for this anyway. It sounds like you want to build a Widget, not use a shortcut.

Comment: Linked question's answer works, I just wanted to know if there is a better way after 10 years :) Anyway I'm doing this only for myself, so noone will hurt if nothing will happen on touching those shortcuts (anyway2: this app is basically a satellite app for Samsung's Bixby routines)

Comment: Nope. No better way. Nothing has changed in that area. Some things just stay the same ;-)